# Excel VBA: Creating a confirmation prompt when a cell is edited

Tags: excel, prompt, vba

I am trying to create a confirmation so that when the cell is blank a prompt launches. If the user clicks confirm, the cell remains blank, else the cell returns to the original value. I have the following but it is not working, I hope that someone can solve this:

```
Private Sub MYtest()
Dim vatcell As Range
Set vatcell = Worksheets("Invoice").Range("D11:D11")
If vatcell = "" Then

 response = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to change the VAT ammount?" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) _
                        & "Value = " & vatcell & Chr(10) & Chr(10) _
                        & "Do you really want to change it?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Value Already Entered")
            If response = vbYes Then
                vatcell = ""
            Else
                vatcell = vatcell
                End If
                End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

The script from Daryll, which is not working: 
[image]

Comment: that is not VB.NET code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two missing pieces to your solution.  First, you need to store the value of the cell before it changed.  Second, you need to connect to an event that tells you when the cell contents have changed.

```
' This is where you store the value before it was changed
Private last_vat As Variant

' this is where you capture the value when the worksheet is first loaded
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim vatcell As Range
    Set vatcell = Range("D11")
    last_vat = vatcell.Value
End Sub

' This is where you respond to a change
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim vatcell As Range
    Set vatcell = Range("D11")
    ' Make sure the cell that changed is the one you are interested in
    If Target = vatcell Then
        ' If it changed from something to nothing
        If vatcell.Value = "" And last_vat <> "" Then
            response = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to clear the VAT ammount?" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) _
                        & "Previous Value = " & last_vat & Chr(10) & Chr(10) _
                        & "Do you really want to change it?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Value Already Entered")
            If response = vbYes Then
                ' Allow the change (by doing nothing)
            Else
                ' Reject the change
                vatcell = last_vat
            End If
        End If
        ' Save changes from non-blank to different non-blank value
        last_vat = vatcell.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Darryl, thanks for replying, sorry about the picture. I am getting a error 9 when the comments are in place, and when I delete the comments, the script is ignored. Any ideas how to fix this? I have put the code in the picture, as I am new to VBA, I don't know if I have made a mistake. Thanks.

Comment: I literally copied the code from the Excel VBA editor verbatim, including the comments.  I'm using Excel 2010.  Your screenshot looks like you've put the code in the right place, so I'm not sure what's wrong.  it looks like you've done this, but here's where I put it:

Comment: First make sure you've got a tab named Invoice.  Then from the developer ribbon tab, click Visual Basic.  Right click on Sheet1 (Invoice) on the left, select View Code.  Copy and paste the code, then close the window.  It works for me (I just tried it again from scratch).

Comment: Thanks Daryyl, no idea what was happening there, but seemed to have solved it now. I have slightly edited the script, to open the prompt when the value is less than or equal too 100, which works, but the prompt keeps   spamming open when I press no. I goes away after about thirty clicks. I thought it was because the new value agrees with this statement, but in your script, if the box is blank, then it should activate as well surely? I have replaced the line above response with this: If vatcell.Value <= 100 And last_vat <> "" Then . Do you know why this is happening.

Comment: If the cell has a value of, say, 30, then the modified If statement will pass over and over.  That's because `vatcell.Value <= 100` (because it is 30), and `last_vat <> ""` (again because it is 30).  Then, when you reject the value, it changes it back to its previous value, which triggers the event handler yet again.  That's why there is a loop.  Perhaps you should change that line to ...`And last_vat <> vatcell.Value`.  Haven't tried it to see if it works, but it might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to have this be an event procedure. The below checks to see if cell D11 have been changed every time the worksheet "Invoice" is changed. Please note that this must be stored on the worksheet "Invoice" in the VBE.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)
Dim vatcell As Range
Set vatcell = Worksheets("Invoice").Range("D11:D11")

If Not Intersect(Target,vatcell) is Nothing Then

 response = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to change the VAT ammount?" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) _
                        & "Value = " & vatcell & Chr(10) & Chr(10) _
                        & "Do you really want to change it?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Value Already Entered")
End If

If response = vbYes Then
vatcell = ""
Else
vatcell = vatcell
End If
End Sub
```